# 24V AC HVAC transformer idle draw

Tags: electrical, hvac, transformer, doorbell

I have a 40VA 24V and an 80VA 24V in my house, one which supplies doorbell power, the other for HVAC. What is the typical idle draw/standby loss for each of these 24V AC transformers when powered but not in use? I know they get slightly warm even when not in use.

Answer (score 2):

To get accurate power usage you will need to look at the manufacturer specifications, or use a meter to measure the power usage.

In round numbers, though, it's easy to guess that these use two or three watts each. If they use less than that, they won't be warm, and if they use more than about 10 watts, a typically sized bell transformer will be too hot to touch.

For a location with typical electric rates (currently about $0.12/kWh) each standby watt costs you about a dollar a year. There are more efficient transformers available, such as toroidal transformers rather than EI-core style. With a transformer that only uses two or three watts, this probably means there's no payback on replacing it with a more efficient unit. If you live in an area with exceptionally high electric rates though the payback might be reasonable.